# OpenCV + RaspberyPI like a room monitor

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm new using opencv and python, my project its about a smarthome.

I managed to install opencv on a raspberrypi and using a webcam.

My program will work on the following three scenarios.
1.A person enters the room, detects face and person, sends message "Dad is in room 1."
2.A person enters the room, detects face but not person, sends message "Unknown person is in room 1"
3. No one is in the room, send a message "No one is in room 1"

Scenarios 1 and 2 I have idea how to solve them, but where I am stuck is in the esceanrio 3. I tried to save the name of the detected person in a variable, if this is empty should send the message, but it has not worked for me.

The code I am using is the following, the problem I have is at the end of the code:

```
import cv2, sys, numpy, os
size = 1
fn_haar = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
fn_dir = 'att_faces'

# Part 1: Create fisherRecognizer
print('Training...')

# Create a list of images and a list of corresponding names
(images, lables, names, id) = ([], [], {}, 0)

# Get the folders containing the training data
for (subdirs, dirs, files) in os.walk(fn_dir):

    # Loop through each folder named after the subject in the photos
    for subdir in dirs:
        names[id] = subdir
        subjectpath = os.path.join(fn_dir, subdir)

        # Loop through each photo in the folder
        for filename in os.listdir(subjectpath):

            # Skip non-image formates
            f_name, f_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
            if(f_extension.lower() not in
                    ['.png','.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.pgm']):
                print("Skipping "+filename+", wrong file type")
                continue
            path = subjectpath + '/' + filename
            lable = id

            # Add to training data
            images.append(cv2.imread(path, 0))
            lables.append(int(lable))
        id += 1
(im_width, im_height) = (112, 92)

# Create a Numpy array from the two lists above
(images, lables) = [numpy.array(lis) for lis in [images, lables]]

# OpenCV trains a model from the images
model = cv2.face.createFisherFaceRecognizer()
model.train(images, lables)




# Part 2: Use fisherRecognizer on camera stream
haar_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(fn_haar)
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:

    # Loop until the camera is working
    rval = False
    while(not rval):
        # Put the image from the webcam into 'frame'
        (rval, frame) = webcam.read()
        if(not rval):
            print("Failed to open webcam. Trying again...")

    # Flip the image (optional)
    frame=cv2.flip(frame,1,0)

    # Convert to grayscalel
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Resize to speed up detection (optinal, change size above)
    mini = cv2.resize(gray, (int(gray.shape[1] / size), int(gray.shape[0] / size)))

    # Detect faces and loop through each one
    faces = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(mini)
    for i in range(len(faces)):
        face_i = faces[i]

        # Coordinates of face after scaling back by `size`
        (x, y, w, h) = [v * size for v in face_i]
        face = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        face_resize = cv2.resize(face, (im_width, im_height))

        # Try to recognize the face
        prediction = model.predict(face_resize)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)

        # [1]
        # Write the name of recognized face
        cv2.putText(frame,
           '%s - %.0f' % (names[prediction[0]],prediction[1]),
           (x-10, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1,(0, 255, 0))
           face = '%S' % (names[prediction[0]]) #Guardar nombre en variable
           #Start to validate the name
           if face != "" : #If a name is detected
               print(face + "Is in the room..") #Print the name in terminal
           elif face == "" : #If a name is not detected
               print("The room is empty...") #Print the text in terminal
               #This last part is where I have problem, when a face is not detected, the text is not printed in the terminal
    # Show the image and check for ESC being pressed
    cv2.imshow('OpenCV', frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

The code I am using is based on the following tutorial: [Face Detection](https://noahingham.com/blog/facerec-python.html)

Any help is appreciated, thank you. Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no faces detected in the room, your code does not enter the `for i in range(len(faces))` loop, which by the way could be simplified to `for i in faces`.

Thus, an `else` at the end of your `for` loop solves your problem:

```
for face in faces:
    do_stuff(face)
else:
    print("room is empty")
```